# How can I get newlines into $.text(), or, how do I make $.append() safe from HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, escaping

I have a chat window (using a `<div>`) that sometimes needs to get multiline entries. Until now, I've simply replaced incoming `\n` with `<br>` and displayed the text with `.append()`. Unfortunately, I've discovered leaving a naked `.append()` based on user input allows the user to insert arbitrary HTML, which will then be executed by the browser. Discovered this while copying a random StackOverflow page to it (to test large sends) and in it was a `<link>` tag, which promptly caused the browser to try to download the CSS file.

Changing this method to use `.text()` solved that particular problem, but now I am unable to display newlines. `<br>`s come through as literal text rather than HTML, and `\n` doesn't seem to have any effect.

Any suggestions? Should I use `.append()` but find some way to escape all HTML tags except `<br>`? Or is there a way to slip newlines in to `.text()`? Or is there a third option I'm missing completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `<pre>` element to preserve newlines in plain text (among other things).

http://www.codetoad.com/html/text/pre_tag.asp

If you want to insert html tags, you should be using `$.html()`, not `$.text()`.

Comment: You can easily override your browser's default `<pre>` styling using CSS: `pre { font-family: Sans-Serif;}` changes all `<pre>`s to use Sans-Serif.

Comment: I'd love to give checkmarks to both this and the `white-space:` answers, but seeing as how `<pre>` was the solution I went with, I had to mark this one as my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `html()` and `<br>` as long as you escape other characters that may be special in HTML. eg.

```
function encodeHTML(s) {
    return s.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}

$('#something').append(encodeHTML(userinput).replace(/\n/g, '<br>'));
```

You might also consider turning `\n\n` into a paragraph break.

The other approach would be to continue using `text()` but set a `white-space: pre-wrap` style to keep the `\n` characters as line breaks

Since IE prior to version 8 doesn't support this you would need a fallback style to set `white-space: pre; word-wrap: break-word;` for that browser. Other older and obscure browsers may also not support this.

Comment: I'll try both of these, but in the meantime, if I wanted to go with the first option, and also wanted to maintain `<a>` tags... I'd have to go with a big regex for this, wouldn't I?

Comment: @Andrew: funny you should ask bobince about regex and HTML. Just a heads up - the `<center>` cannot hold. :P

Comment: Mere <a>narchy is loos'd upon the world.

Comment: heh. If you've got `<a>` tags (which you want to be real tags) *and* `<` and `&` characters (which are not supposed to represent markup) in your string, you've got a real problem. It would not be possible to reconstruct the desired HTML for such a case, with a regex or otherwise.

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter too much. The input problem doesn't matter for <a> tags, because it's not like the person is posting a link to themselves. The server can handle replacement of tags in this case.

Comment: I'd love to give a checkmark to this answer, as it enlightened me to the existence of `white-space:`, but I went with the `<pre>` solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to be able to chat HTML (As text):

You can escape the HTML elements first, by replacing < with &lt; and > with &gt; and then replace the new lines with BR tags.